# Could "mismodify" be a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, prefixes, productive-affixes

I've never seen it in any dictionary, and searching on Google gives fairly few, almost irrelevant results, but it seems like it could potentially be a word, albeit perhaps a technical one at that. It would be defined as "to modify incorrectly or accidentally."

This could refer to, for example, a file which was modified in an unintentional way, though it really doesn't have to be limited to technological contexts.

Comment: Definition of mis- prefix.
> 1. a prefix applied to various parts of speech, meaning “ill,” “mistaken,” “wrong,” “wrongly,” “incorrectly,” or simply negating: mistrial; misprint; mistrust. Origin of mis-1 Expand. Old English. (dictionary.com)

Yes, from this meanng mismodify would work.

Comment: @Prodnegel This shows a lack of understanding of the fact that productivity in English is a gradable rather than an absolute feature.

Comment: a short answer: it might, but it isn't.

Comment: @Centaurus William Safire has used it [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=aR8k-2cNNJ8C&pg=PT440&dq=mismodified&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4w6f0sr3QAhXJslQKHYMnBuc4ChDoAQhCMAg#v=onepage&q=mismodified&f=false)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, what are you talking about? First off, I never said anything about productivity. Second of all, a thing's productivity can surely be graded. Similar to how foreign in this example could be graded "She sounded slightly foreign.", one could be "slightly" productive, where productivity is measured in whatever form the medium suggests.

Comment: @ Prodnegel  'Definition of mis- prefix. > 1. a prefix applied to various parts of speech, meaning “ill,” “mistaken,” “wrong,” “wrongly,” “incorrectly,” or simply negating ...' doesn't mean one can form a valid new word by attaching mis- to any candidate. Dictionaries are almost always the best guide to what are words and what aren't. And to meanings: 'productive' has a specific meaning in the formation of words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has already discovered through research that the word does not exist.

Comment: Ah, but what does Safire know about English??

Comment: Skeleton, there is nothing wrong with "mismodify", meaning to modify erroneously.  It's a perfectly valid use of the prefix "mis-", which is a prefix that can be used relatively freely to modify the meaning of verbs that refer an activity.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining it to me! Word doesn't seem to recognize it as a word, either, haha! I was *not* expecting people to start commenting like crazy on this post... :P

Answer (score 2):

A Google Books search yields two matches for *mismodify*. The earlier of these is from Mervyn Falk, [*A Cleft Palate Team Addresses the Speech Clinician*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZnlsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mismodify%22&dq=%22mismodify%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyh7jvg77QAhVbHGMKHaCyCmgQ6AEIIjAC) (1971) [combined snippets]:

> Keep in mind that we have defined the production of a speech signal as a modified voiced or voiceless airstream. Now what is done to overmodify or **mismodify**, as you might conceive of it, has really only to do with getting that child into the therapy situation. From here on, we are interested in what is correct.

And the later is from [*Rivista Di Linguistica*](https://books.google.com/books?id=i7EoAQAAIAAJ&q=%22and+hence+not+adjoined+to,+its+modifiee%22&dq=%22and+hence+not+adjoined+to,+its+modifiee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH0dyNhr7QAhVH12MKHWa0CLIQ6AEIHDAA), volume 12 (2000):

> ***3. Adverbs and movement in Romance***
>
> Morphologically motivated head movement creates situations of surface **mismodification**—situations in which an adverb is not next to, and hence not adjoined to, its modifiee in surface structure. So in the now standard Emonds/Pollockian (Emonds 1978; Pollock 1989) surface structure of French we find (8a) analyzed as (8b), where the adverb appears to **mismodify** the VP, as it does not seem to be adjoined to it in the following: ...

This second example, as you can see, also contains an instance of *mismodification*, as do eleven other Google Books matches going back to this one in [*Modern Exposition: A Textbook in Expository Writing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=erFRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22mismodification%22&dq=%22mismodification%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK4NjChr7QAhUM6GMKHW0lDNwQ6AEIMzAE) (1942):

> A particularly crude type of **mismodification** appears in
>
> > The persons the engineer is addressing, either oral or written. . . .
>
> Since *oral* and *written* are adjectives and can modify only substantives, they must modify *engineer*, or possibly *persons*.

Joel Bowman & Berndine Branchaw, [*How to Write Proposals that Produce*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wrUiPIzFVpcC&pg=PA67&dq=%22mismodification%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK4NjChr7QAhUM6GMKHW0lDNwQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22mismodification%22&f=false) (1992) identifies "mismodification" as a type of grammar error:

> **Mismodification**
>
> Misplaced modifiers modify the wrong word, phrase, or clause. A dangling modifier has no word, phrase, or clause that it can logically modify. Avoid **mismodification** by placing the modifier close to the word, phrase, or clause that it modifies.

Google Books searches also turn up nine probable matches for *mismodified* from as early as David Ebert, [*Synthesis and Localization of Lysosomal Enzymes in Secretory Mutants ...*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JVBuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22function+improperly+because+they+are+mismodified%22&dq=%22function+improperly+because+they+are+mismodified%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM9vHXi77QAhVY82MKHee7AjUQ6AEIHjAA) (1986), which uses the term on five different pages, including page 49 [combined snippets]:

> Other proteins, essential for the operation of the lysosomal system, may function improperly because they are **mismodified**, or something may be wrong with the targeting and secretion pathway which affects lysosomal enzyme modification, but is independent of it.

So a whole family of words built on *mismodify* has existed for several decades, serving writers functioning in fields ranging from speech therapy to biochemistry to oncology to grammar. Most of the instances that Google Books searches identify, however, are clustered in the last two areas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *mismodified* means exactly what you imagine it to mean. That’s how English affixes like this work: you combine a common prefix and a common base word to create a word that everyone who knows those two components already knows what means.

It is much easier to prove that something **does** exist than that it does **not**, for the affirmative a simple existence proof suffices. Here then is not one but four such existence proofs:

> 1. And now to the event itself, so often mismodified by *abortive* (“tending to be cut short”), better modified by aborted (“terminate early”), and best buy *failed*, *unsuccessful* or the breezier *fizzled*: “It was described as a *coup,” writes the Reverend Donald Hendricks of Yonkers....* 
>      —[***Watching My Language:: Adventures in the Word Trade***](https://goo.gl/w0pi1v), by [**William Safire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Safire)
> 2. However, that does not imply that chromatin modification is not reversible. In fact, chromatin can become mismodified in certain cancers, an this shows that, although important, the change of chromatin is not permanent. 
>    —[***The Mysterious Waves Of Living Cells***](https://goo.gl/0f6nU0), by Hubert Rudakemwa
> 3. The ER has a robust quality control system that prevents misfolded and mismodified proteins from exiting the ER and being transported on to the Golgi. 
>    —[Could inhibition of the proteasome cause mad cow disease?](http://www.cell.com/trends/biotechnology/fulltext/S0167-7799(03)00026-X), ***Trends in Biotechnology***, Volume 21, Issue 4, April 2003
> 4. One possible function of endonucleolytic tRNA cleavage might be to degrade unprocessed, mismodified, or uncharged tRNAs. 
>    —[tRNA cleavage is a conserved response to oxidative stress in eukaryotes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2553748/) ***RNA.*** 2008 Oct; 14(10): 2095–2103.

Every native speaker immediately and intuitively knows what this easily recognized word means, howsoever scarce samples of it may be “in the wild”. So you’re perfectly safe here.

Notice that all four of those citations are from published authors who clearly know what they’re talking about, not just some worthless graffiti from the likes of Urban Dictionary or Twitter.

I don’t know about you, but I for one elect ***not*** to argue with [William Safire On Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Safire). :)

Comment: I don't know whether 'modify when one shouldn't' or 'modify to produce an unacceptable result' is intended.